# Why is `tex.sprint` deferred when handling `process_input_buffer`?

Tags: luatex, directlua, callback

```latex
%!TEX program=lualatex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\def\specialRead{\directlua{
    luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer', function (line) 
        if line:find('^\\offSpecialRead') then return end
        tex.sprint("line: " .. line .. "$")
        return 'Sanitized line'
    end, 'special read')
}}%
\def\offSpecialRead{\directlua{
    luatexbase.remove_from_callback('process_input_buffer', 'special read')
}}%
\specialRead
a
b
\offSpecialRead c
d

\edef\e{\directlua{tex.sprint('')}f}
\verb|\e: [|\meaning\e\verb|]|
\end{document}
```

The previous `tex.sprint`s are deferred until another `tex.sprint` in the definition of `\e`.

[image: compiled output]

Comment: Probably a bug. Or just "it is what it is". Either way a workaround would be to, well, embed the content you want to print into the line itself.

Comment: Lua interface is a bit limited. Sometimes you just have to deal with it, using e.g. TeX coroutine to execute TeX code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I worked it out after reading the source code.

[`tex.sprint` stores string to a list](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/6cde127/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/lua/ltexlib.c#L98)

```c
#define  write_spindle spindles[spindle_index]
#define  read_spindle  spindles[(spindle_index-1)]
...
static int luac_store(lua_State * L, int i, int partial, int cattable)
{
    ...
    luacstrings++;
    rn = (rope *) xmalloc(sizeof(rope));
    rn->text = st;
    rn->tsize = (unsigned) tsize;
    rn->tok = tok;
    rn->nod = nod;
    rn->next = NULL;
    rn->partial = partial;
    rn->cattable = cattable;
    /* add */
    if (write_spindle.head == NULL) {
        write_spindle.head = rn;
    } else {
        write_spindle.tail->next = rn;
    }
    write_spindle.tail = rn;
    write_spindle.complete = 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Spindles are inputted by `read_spindle`, and the `write_spindle` becomes `read_spindle` only when `luacstring_start()` does `spindle_size++`.
And `luacstring_start()` is called by [`lua_string_start()`](https://github.com/TeX-Live/luatex/blob/16f2f7c88eeef85ce988cbe595481fa714f5dfc9/source/texk/web2c/luatexdir/tex/inputstack.c#L891), which is invoked after a lua code executed in the main loop, each time preceded by checking `luacstrings > 0`.

```
void lua_string_start(void)
{
    ...
    luacstring_start(iindex);
}
```

The variable `luacstrings` is resetted to 0 before these lua codes, and is changed only in `luac_store`.

Unlike explicit `\directlua{...tex.print(...)...}`, the callback functions are invoked out of the main loop, so `lua_string_start()` is not called until another explicit `tex.print`.